# Are parser generators useful for parsing a shell language?

Tags: language-design, compiler, parsing, interpreters, shell

From my understanding, parser generators accept as input some form of **context-free** grammar description. The context-sensitive features are handled during semantic rather than syntactic analysis (please correct me if this is wrong).

Since shell languages inherently have *a lot of* context-sensitive features, is it worthwhile using a parser generator? If not, what techniques could be used for a precise definition and parsing of a shell language?

**EDIT:**
In conclusion: my understanding of what *context-sensitive grammar* means was wrong.

Comment: Citation needed on the context-sensitiveness of shell languages...

Comment: “context-free” and ”context-sensitive“ has a *specific* meaning in computer science that does not match it's everyday usage. Most programming languages incl. shell languages have a context-free syntax. In practice, it's often possible to extend CFGs with context-sensitive features by introducing pseudotokens, e.g. INDENT and DEDENT tokens in Python or a token representing a word boundary. However, such approaches require scannerless parsers or a more complex lexer.

Comment: Upvoting given the edits and good comments/answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Context-free grammars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) are grammars where the left side of every production rule is a non terminal term (aka an abstract grammar construct) whereas the right side can be a mix of terminals (aka tokens that you find in the language) and non-terminals.

Context-sensitive grammars are more tricky, since both the left and the right side of production rules can be a mix of terminals and non terminals. To express it simply, the meaning of a term depends on its surroundings (aka “context”).

[Command shells](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_10) usually have a straightforward grammar that can be expressed with context-free grammars. I’d really wonder if you’d really need a context sensitive one.

I’d tempted to say that command shells are easily implemented using simple top down  interpreter (see also the [interpreter pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern)) and that parser generators seem to me somewhat an overkill. But I have not seen your language so I cannot tell for sure that it makes sense in your case.